# how to comment on particular photo using FBRequestConnection(Facebook Graph API) in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to post comment on particular photo...how can i achieve that using FBRequestConnection (Graph API), I also used Graph API Explorer, but i am not getting how to do that.please can any one explain me in brief.?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use graphAPI you try with this code..

```
NSString *commentid=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/comments",groupId];
NSMutableDictionary *dictVar=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[dictVar setValue:textView.text forKey:@"message"];
FbGraphResponse *response=[fbgraph doGraphPost:commentid withPostVars:dictVar];
NSLog(@"%@",response.htmlResponse);
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

To post a comment on any {object_id} use the following snippet of code

```
 NSDictionary *param = @{@"message": commentText};
FBRequestConnection *connection = [[FBRequestConnection alloc] init];
FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/comments",mediaId] parameters:param HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[connection addRequest:request completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        aCompletion(NO);
    }else{
        aCompletion(YES);
    }
}];
[connection start];
```

Hope this will be helpful.